# Vectorize the sum of unique columns

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vectorization

There are multiple occurrence of same combination of values in different rows of matlab, for example 1 1 in first and second row. I want to remove all those duplicates but adding the values in third column. In case of 1 1 it will be 7. Finally I want to create a similarity matrix as shown below in Answer. I don't mind 2*values in diagonals because I will not be considering diagonal elements in further work. The code below does this but it is not vectorized. Can this be vectorized somehow. Example is given below.

```
datain = [ 1 1 3; 
       1 1 4; 
       1 2 5; 
       1 2 4; 
       1 2 3; 
       1 3 8; 
       1 3 7; 
       1 3 12; 
       2 2 22; 
       2 2 77;
       2 3 111;
       2 3 113;
       3 3 456;
       3 3 568];  
cmp1=unique(datain(:,1));
cmp1sz=size(cmp1,1);
cmp2=unique(datain(:,2));
cmp2sz=size(cmp2,1);
thetotal=zeros(cmp1sz,cmp2sz);

for i=1:size(datain,1)
 for j=1:cmp1sz
     for k=1:cmp2sz
         if datain(i,1)==cmp1(j,1) && datain(i,2)== cmp2(k,1)
             thetotal(j,k)=thetotal(j,k)+datain(i,3);
             thetotal(k,j)=thetotal(k,j)+datain(i,3);
         end
     end
 end
end
```

The answer is

```
14          12          27

12         198         224

27         224        2048
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a poster case for using [ACCUMARRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html).

```
thetotal = accumarray(datain(:,1:2),datain(:,3),[],@sum,0);

%# to make the array symmetric, you simply add its transpose

thetotal = thetotal + thetotal'

thetotal =
          14          12          27
          12         198         224
          27         224        2048
```

**EDIT**

So what if `datain` does not contain only integer values? In this case, you can still construct a table, but e.g. `thetotal(1,1)` will not correspond to `datain(1,1:2) == [1 1]`, but to the smallest entry in the first two columns of `datain`.

```
[uniqueVals,~,tmp] = unique(reshape(datain(:,1:2),[],1));
correspondingIndices = reshape(tmp,size(datain(:,1:2)));
thetotal = accumarray(correspondingIndices,datain(:,3),[],@sum,0);
```

The value at `[1 1]` now corresponds to the row `[uniqueVals(1) uniqueVals(1)]` in the first two cols of `datain`.